# Express - refresh view variable when database contents change

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using Express and I am generating pages from database. On server start I have navigation generation.

This block is executed on server start:

```
database.connect()
        .then(() => {
          generators.navigation();
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          process.exit();
        });
```

I have this code that generates navigation:

```
generators.navigation = function(){
  var db = require('./database.js').db;
  var data = db.collection('navigation').find({},{_id:0,path:1,title:1});
  var nav = []
  data.on('data', doc => {
    nav.push(doc)
  })
  data.on('end', () => {
    generators.navigation = nav;
  })
}
```

Which is then used in page rendering:

```
for (let page of pages) {
  if(req.params.path === page.path){
    res.render(page.type, {
      page:page,
      navigation:generators.navigation,
      helpers:helpers
    });
  }//if
}//for
```

And in my view (using handlebars):

```
{{#if_eq page.contents.nav.type 'default'}}
  {{#each navigation}}
    <a class="item no-mobile" href="{{this.path}}">{{this.title}}</a>
  {{/each}}
{{/if_eq}}
```

The problem is that when new object is inserted in database, this doesn't update navigation, that happens because this code is only executed at server start, and it is required to restart server in order to read new changes in database.

Which is recommended way for it to watch for database updates and refresh navigation object when database is updated?

Comment: Probably the most appropriate will be a solution that triggers a navigation structure renewal on each database update, you can use WebSocket for real time polling.
http://socket.io/ is a good library to go with for real time updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't write generators.navigation(); on server start . There are hooks provided in nodejs that get fired before request /after request so you can use this hooks to call generators.navigation() function. As iam assuming there would be on function that will add nav items to database . So as soon as that request is completed you can call generators.navigation() in that requests after request hook

Comment: Database is filled by totally different application written in PHP.

Comment: in that case make middle ware function like

Comment: function myMiddleware (req, res, next) {
   if (req.method === 'GET') { 
     // Do some code
   }

   // keep executing the router middleware
   next()
}

app.use(myMiddleware)                                                                                          so in this function call generators.navigation(); so it will get triggered for every request

Comment: for you no need to check  if (req.method === 'GET')

Comment: That is a good solution. However, it requires other app to send `get` requests to my node app whenever it is used to update database. I am looking for inner solution since I do not have control on how php app will act while generating content.

Comment: In that case you can use node-cron module. To write cron jobs that will trigger generators.navigation(); Or socket.io()

Comment: I have never used socket.io, but I will give it a try, meantime, I talked to other developer and asked him to provide get requests when database is updated. This seems to be really good idea. Thanks man!